# TeamCity Upgrade Issue

Tags: teamcity

We are trying to migrate our production TeamCity from version 9.1.4 to version 10.0.5 The upgrade process works well and everything works once I get onto the web UI. The problem is that, after a couple of minutes the build queue suddenly starts to build up and it goes all the way up to 3,000. I'm not sure how to clear that or how to do a queue purge and i'm not sure why that's happening. Before doing the upgrade process I made sure that the artifacts directory was in the spot it needed to be before running the maintainDB restore command. Would anyone happen to know why this is happening?

Just a note - this is a test environment to test out the functionality of the new version so none of the build agents are actually attached to this test teamcity as the build queue goes up to 3,000.

Another issue i'm noticing is under Project underneath Project-Related Setting there are no active project according to TeamCity. However, on the home UI I can see all the active projects, which is odd

Any help or information would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The teamcity support told you what about the issue ?

Comment: Never heard back from them. Fixed the issue by adding  a couple more flags to the backup taken when using the maintainDB utility. Specifically -L  to also backup all the logs. Once that was done the build queue no longer sky rocketed to 3,000

Answer (score 0):

Issue ended up being a couple of missing flags in the maintaindb command. Needed to make sure -L was set as a parameter, so that when TeamCity backed up it also grabbed all the historical data